# How does a computer proceed nested while loops?

Tags: while-loop

I am learning programming with Swift Playgrounds and I do not understand something in the lection "nested loops". I try to generalize it because my question is very fundamental about how computers run down the code. So here is kind of a pseudo-code:

While A {While A {!A}, A}

It says that while A do the following: while A, do Non-A, otherwise A.

Question #1: Let's say the initial status is A. It means the While-loop is initiated, and so is the nested While-Loop that does !A. I would expect that at this point *both* While-Loops stop because both conditions are false. But what seems to happen is this: only the inner while loop (that does !A) stops because of !A and then A is done and then the outside While Loop gets checked again and is initiated (because A is true) and the whole thing repeats infinitely. Is that observation true? Is that how a computer proceeds nested while loops, just the inner one and if this inner one fails he switches to the outer one?

Question #2: I ask because we do not think that way. If a human would execute an order like: *while A do the following: while A, do Non-A, otherwise A*, he'd abandon the whole order after the inner while loop procuded !A because he'd see that now both loops collapse due to !A. At least I think so or do I think wrongly here?

Answer (score 0):

Nesting a code block inside of another code block doesn't change how either of them behave.  Code still executes, statement by statement, in logical order.

For a loop, that logical order is that the terminating condition of the loop is evaluated between each iteration of the loop.  It doesn't have some kind of watcher or notification system to examine every operation within the loop and interrupt the execution of the code.

For example:

```
x = true;
while (x == true) {
  x = false;
  x = true;
}
```

This loop will continue indefinitely because the condition `x == true` isn't evaluated after every line of code, it's evaluated after the entire code block has finished and the loop iterates again.

Nesting one loop inside of another doesn't change this behavior.

```
x = true;
while (x == true) {
  // do any variety of things, maybe one line of code or
  // maybe a million lines of code, maybe call methods,
  // maybe include loops or if-blocks, doesn't matter
}
```

> If a human would execute an order like: while A do the following: while A, do Non-A, otherwise A, he'd abandon the whole order

Would he?  I wouldn't.  Different humans think in different ways.  If the instructions are ambiguous, results will vary.  Computers on the other hand can't tolerate ambiguous instructions.  The logic they perform is entirely deterministic.  If a compiler/interpreter/etc. were to find a situation where the instruction is ambiguous then, unlike a human, it wouldn't make an intuitive decision on the matter.  It would just throw an error.

That's not to say that *code* is always unambigous.  There's plenty of obtuse and difficult to follow code written by humans.  Or written by humans who may not have understood how the computer will execute that code.  But if that code runs then it's not ambiguous to the computer.  Even if we as humans struggle to understand what's going to happen in the code, the computer will still make it happen.

Answer (score 0):

#2 The second question show the human have implied

> while A do the following: while A, do Non-A, otherwise A

A computer could execute:

- while A do the following:( if A ,(while A, do Non-A), otherwise A)

or

- while A do the following: ((while A, do Non-A) if A, , otherwise A))

and the pseudo code you supply is

- while A do the following: ((while A, do Non-A) A)

#1 The observation is true for the pseudo code supply